# How to rotate image with new Image()?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm creating new image using

```
img = new Image();
img.src = image_url;
```

Then How can I rotate that image before display it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/2367595/1190388

Comment: Did you try something?

Answer (score -1):

The raphael.js library supports easier image rotation:

http://raphaeljs.com/image-rotation.html

Comment: Including an entire library only to perform this simple task is overkill. One could suggest using GD or imagik to actually create a rotated version of the image as well... I really don't think that this answer would help the OP nor future visitors.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, although a more tactful response exists. Unless you were talking about the Javascript GD (and not the PHP one), the question specifies a client-side implementation.. hence using a JS library.

Comment: Yea - I might have gone overboard with the PHP thing (sorry bout that).. I still think that including an entire library only for image rotation when it is available with CSS is still overkill...

Answer (score -1):

You can do it with css transform:

```
var img = new Image();
img.src = "http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/a7d7d1a56e455ea29f370251e3582986?s=32&d=identicon&r=PG";
document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(img);
img.style.Transform = "rotate(90deg)"
img.style.MozTransform = "rotate(90deg)"
img.style.webkitTransform = "rotate(90deg)"
```