# jsPDF width/height show undefined when set

Tags: javascript, jspdf

I'm using jsPDF to create a PDF doc on Chrome v67, 64 bit. I've attempted to set the width and height of PDF document using the code below as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36472094/how-to-set-image-to-fit-width-of-the-page-using-jspdf):

```
var doc = new jsPDF("p", "mm", "a4");
var width = doc.internal.pageSize.width;
var height = doc.internal.pageSize.height;
```

The problem I encountered was that the width and height were not being applied. For giggles I added the following line of code after the code above:

```
console.log("AT#1: width=" + width + ", heigth=" + height);
```

only to find that the values of the width and height when I output to the console are undefined:

```
AT#1: width=undefined, heigth=undefined
```

I've searched S.O. and Google but have not found anything that suggest a possible solution or reason why they are undefined. Currently this has me stumped. Any ideas or suggestions?

Comment: You misspelled “height” as “heigth” in your `console.log`, but that shouldn't matter since it's only in the output string. The variable name after it `height` does seem to correctly match your declaration `var height`.

Comment: Links to aid answerers: jsPDF’s [documentation](https://rawgit.com/MrRio/jsPDF/master/docs/) and [source code](https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51103806/578288) points out on the question [How to set image to fit width of the page using jspdf?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36472094/578288) you linked, the API in later versions changed from `.width` and `.height` to `.getWidth()` and `.getHeight()`.

The following code should work when you try it on [jsPDF’s online demo](https://rawgit.com/MrRio/jsPDF/master/):

```js
var doc = new jsPDF();

var width = doc.internal.pageSize.getWidth();
var height = doc.internal.pageSize.getHeight();

console.log("AT#1: width=" + width + ", height=" + height);
```

What is logged:

```
AT#1: width=210.0015555555555, height=297.0000833333333
```

Comment: this did the trick. Very much appreciated. This was a total bonehead on my part. I had scrolled through the same link you provided but did not catch that they changed from properties to actual function calls.

Comment: In Latest version i.e. 1.4.1 i did not found these methods  doc.internal.pageSize.getWidth(); and getHeight() , as it looks like they revert old code in new jsPDF version. i am still facing width/height are undefined issue.