# jsPDF - Content height increased

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, jspdf

Thanks for reviewing my question.

I have used jsPDF with Angular 12 to download PDF from my dashboard. I have attached code snippets and images with the expected and current output.

I want to fit all the content on A4 size page, but somehow font height getting increase and PDF content looks odd.

```
downloadPDF(order: any) {
  let DATA: any = document.getElementById('htmlData');
  html2canvas(DATA,
    {
      scale: 3,
      onclone: function (clonedDoc: any) {
        clonedDoc.getElementById('htmlData').style.display = 'block';
    }
    }).then((canvas) => {
      const contentDataURL = canvas.toDataURL('image/png')  
      let pdf = new jsPDF("p", "pt", "a4"); // A4 size page of PDF  
      var width = pdf.internal.pageSize.getWidth();
      var height = pdf.internal.pageSize.getHeight();
      let position = 0;  
      pdf.addImage(contentDataURL, 'PNG', 0, position, width, height, "", "FAST") 
      
      // Save or display the PDF
      var today = this.dateToYMD(new Date());
      pdf.save(`${order.customerInfo.firstName}- ${order.customerInfo.lastName}-${today}.pdf`);
  });
}
```

Expected Output:-
[image]

Current Output:-
[image]

Thanks in advance for at lease reviewing my question.

Comment: Did you try changing `scale`? Also try passing zeroes for `width` and `height`.
`let pdf = new jsPDF("l", "px", "a4");`
`pdf.addImage(canvas, "PNG", 0, 0, 0, 0);`
This worked for me.

Comment: Also try in different browser.

Comment: @MilosStojanovic I tried both the suggestions but none of the solutions worked.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36472094/how-to-set-image-to-fit-width-of-the-page-using-jspdf
Does this help?

Comment: @RonakDumaniya Without the sensitive information if you give a stackblitz, with the issue replicated, I can try to fix it!

Comment: Why not use jspdf html method? it will be much cleaner and fit the pdf alignments